# ActiveRecord4でpolymorphicなScoreの値の合計値でソートしたい。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sort, rails-activerecord

TeamモデルとPlayerモデルがhas_manyの関係でpolymorphicなScoreモデルを持つというような構成で 
チームやプレイヤーに得点を付けることができるシステムを作成しています。

チームに所属しているプレイヤーの一覧を表示するときに 
Scoreモデルが持つvalueカラムの合計値を使ってソートをかけたいです。

Playerモデルに以下のスコープを作成しました。

```
scope :sorted, -> {
  joins(:scores)
  .group("players.id")
  .order("sum(scores.value) desc")
}
```

しかし、これだとひとつもスコアを付けられていない要素が含まれずに 
スコアを付けられている要素の中でソートが行われてしまいます。

スコアが付けられていない要素に対してはデフォルトで０点ということにして 
全ての要素を取得したいのですがどうすればよいでしょうか？

Comment: sortのタグを追加しました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

似たようなモデル構造のプロジェクトがあったので、実際に動かしながら試してみました。

回答からまず書くと、たぶんこんな感じでいけるんじゃないかと思います。

```
scope :sorted, -> {
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN scores ON scores.scorable_id = players.id AND scores.scorable_type = 'Player'")
  .group("players.id")
  .order("COALESCE(SUM(scores.value), 0) DESC")
}
```

`scorable` というのはこちらの想像で付けた名前です。ここは実際のカラムの名前に変更してください。
ちなみにクラス定義でいうと、こんな定義をイメージしています。

```
class Player
  has_many :scores, as: :scorable

class Score
  belongs_to :scorable, polymorphic: true
```

あと、`COALESCE` というのはPostgresでNULL（=スコアが付けられていない要素）を2番目の引数の値（=0）に変更する関数です。
使用するRDBMSによっては別の関数を使うかもしれません。

補足事項として、Railsで外部結合（LEFT OUTER JOIN）を使う場合は、`includes` + `references` をよく使うのですが、これを使うと scores のカラムも一緒に取得しようとするためにSQLエラーが起きます。

コードで書くとこんな感じです。（エラーが起きる）

```
scope :sorted, -> {
  includes(:scores)
  .references(:scores)
  .group("players.id")
  .order("COALESCE(SUM(scores.value), 0) DESC")
}
```

なので、今回は（極力避けたい）生のSQLでテーブルをJOINしています。

あと、もう一点だけ。
KoRoN さんも書いているように、[Squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel)というgemを使うとJOINをスッキリ書けます。

```
scope :sorted, -> {
  joins{ scores.outer }
  .group("players.id")
  .order("COALESCE(SUM(scores.value), 0) DESC")
}
```

以上、ご参考までに。

Answer (score 1):

例によって、より良い回答が付くまでの繋ぎとして、粗い回答を付けておきます。

要求されている操作は SQL 的には `LEFT OUTER JOIN` という操作です。
検索する際はこれをキーワードにすると良さそうです。

検索の結果、こんな記事: [Railsで生SQLを書かずにLEFT JOINする方法](http://qiita.com/unosk/items/403d0fdaf91ca86aa099) が見つかりました。
こちらの記事によれば `includes` を使う、もしくは [squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) を使うということのようです。